# create vue 3 component on the fly based on a object using resolveDynamicComponent

Tags: vuejs3, vue-sfc

My goal is to let users create vue components based on objects using resolveDynamicComponent. While refresh page, render and data binding goes well, but after that, it gets some error and makes the rendered item disappear.

```html
<template>
  <abc/>
</template>

<script setup>
import {resolveDynamicComponent} from 'vue'

const abc = resolveDynamicComponent(
    {
      name: 'abc',
      setup: () => {
        const test = 'Test'
      },
      template: '<div>{{test}}</div>'
    }
)
</script>
```

Error

```sh
Hydration completed but contains mismatches.
hydrate @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3136
```